# block access to a table from any user except one

Tags: mysql

I have a database with many many tables.

I want to block any users, except one, from accessing this table.  All the users will also need to be able to access any future tables created in such database, and naturally it is not possible for me to add/remove access to those tables as some are temporary tables created just scripting purpose.

Something like:

```
GRANT ALL PRIV ON *.* TO user123 ...
REVOKE ALL PRIV ON mydb.table FROM user123
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If some tables are temporary, why not just create them as `TEMPORARY` tables? Then they will only be accessible by the session which created them.

You can easily grant permissions on tables and then revoke for an individual table, but there's no way to easily maintain that going forward.

Another option is to simply put the table which needs different permissions in a separate database. Of course it managing permissions for two databases, so it could be messy, but it's somewhat closer to the goal.

Comment: different databases could actually be possible.  This is a huge system, but a search replace and a few seconds of downtime might be what does the trick.  I will keep the question open to see if anyone else has a better solution, but so far this sounds the best.

Answer (score 0):

There's a good reference guide to table privileges [here](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/MySQL/The-MySQL-Grant-Tables/2/). Think it has what you need. Other privileges are mentioned earlier in the same guide if you need those too.